# Combining multiple DSLs together in chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

In chef recipe I have multiple resource get called like

```
template "blah_path/file1.conf"
  source "recipe/file1.conf"
  variables ( k1: v1) 
end
template "blah_path/file2.conf"
  source "recipe/file2.conf"
  variables ( k2: v2) 
end
.
.
template "blah_path/file10.conf"
  source "recipe/file10.conf"
  variables ( k10: v10) 
end
```

Is it possible to combine steps like above under single resource ?  TMK if I try to create my own resource/providers, I can not call other resource inside it directly.

Is there any better way to abstract such code trail while writing chef recipe ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could create a chef LWRP, definition or library. Personally I prefer that my recipe explicitly lists managed files, sometimes abstract hides the details of the entities under management by chef. If your recipe is very long have you considered breaking it up into smaller recipes, included by a default recipe?

Comment: Mark, Thank you for suggestion about breaking recipes into smaller ones and then include them in default which will make cleaner representation of logic. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hiding it in LWRP you can just DRY up the code with some loops.
Depending on your exact code something like this would work:

```
files = { 'file1.conf' => {k1: v1}, 'file2.conf' => {k2: v2, k3: v3}, ... }
files.each do |filename, params|
  template "blah_path/#{filename}"
    source "recipe/#{filename}"
    variables params
  end
end
```

When using hosted Chef I like to store the application configuration in encoded data bags and generate config files using the code below:

```
configs = Chef::DataBag.load('config').keys
configs.each do |config|
  json = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("config", config, secret)[node.chef_environment]
  yaml = {node.chef_environment => json}.to_yaml
  file "#{node[cookbook_name]['project_dir']}/shared/config/#{config}.yml" do
    content yaml
    owner "ubuntu"
    group "ubuntu"
    mode "0770"
    action :create
  end
end
```